# Насколько необходимо в наши дни писать get / set методы при работе с внутренними переменными?

Tags: ооп, оод

Ранее было чуть ли не железобетонное правило писать `get`/`set` методы при работе с внутренними свойствами объектов. Мотивация по их написанию была такой: если потребуется написать более сложную логику при работе со свойством объекта, то внутри `get`/`set` метода это сделать значительно проще.

За несколько лет, читая разные куски кода написанных классов, я всегда видел только то, что такие методы очень простые: `return this.__private_var` или `this__private_var = value`.

Возникает вопрос: а может эта рекомендация потеряла смысл в наши дни? При современных средствах разработки, которые подскажут чуть ли не каждый неверный шаг, как бы ты не пытался отстрелить себе ногу, это правило, наверное, уже не имеет смысла?

Comment: не думаю, что на такой вопрос можно ответить обстоятельно для всех языков программирования с поддержкой ООП...

Comment: ИМХО, смысл get/set исключительно в возможности использования различных средств автогенерации кода. Во всех остальных случаях - это отличный способ сделать программу запутанной и усложнить ее сопровождение. Пример - вылет на Eхception без предупреждения в строке типа p=0;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Мотивация писать геттеры и сеттеры - не только упрощение описания сложной логики при работе со свойством объекта. Мотиваций несколько:

1. Сокрытие деталей. Внутренние свойства, они на то и внутренние. Знание о том, что блок питания можно запустить без кнопки и вообще без нагрузки, просто замкнув два контакта, совсем не говорит о том, что кнопка питания на корпусе лишняя, бесполезная и вообще усложняет всё. Знание о том, что колёса управляются рулевыми тягами, вовсе не говорит, что, управляя автомобилем, мы должны сами руками их тянуть. Есть готовая рулевая система (которая сразу синхронизирует поворот колес за нас) и интерфейс (в виде руля).
2. Возможность добавить свое поведение. Например, иногда мне приходилось добавлять свои геттеры и сеттеры, переводить весь код на их использование (что само по себе времязатратно) и добавлять логирование их вызовов, чтобы посмотреть, насколько активно используется свойство, откуда оно меняется и с какой очередностью. Все было бы куда проще, если бы автор изначально не поленился и написал свой класс с геттерами и сеттерами.
3. Возможность контролировать и ограничивать доступ к чтению/записи свойства по любым причинам и, как следствие, предотвратить "поломку" внутреннего состояния объекта. Например, есть класс Ellipse. У него есть методы, которые используют [каноническое уравнение эллипса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%81#%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). При отсутствии геттеров и сеттеров можно без проблем сделать `myellipse.a = 0;`, что впоследствии может стать сюрпризом при попытке какого-то другого метода вычислить `(x*x)/(a*a)`. При наличии сеттера можно сделать что-то вроде (пример ниже) и получить исключение при инициализации (что несколько приятнее звонков посреди ночи со словами "твоя программа закрылась с ошибкой, нужно срочно фиксить"):

```
function set_a(new_a_value):
    if new_a_value == 0:
        throw Exception("Невозможно установить `a` равным 0")

    this.a = new_a_value
```

Средства разработки, конечно, во многом помогают, но они не укажут проблемы в плохой архитектуре и логических ошибках. И если очень сильно хочется отстрелить себе ногу, то ни одна IDE от этого не убережет.

В целом, если говорить в общем смысле, то смысл использовать эти методы есть. Если же в узком смысле, то тут нужно присмотреться к задаче.